# AngularJS with TypeScript Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert an AngularJS app I built a while ago to TypeScript. I've written what I think is correct for the initial app.ts file, but upon compiling & trying to open my app in the browser, I get a **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]** error in the console.

I've added all the code to the Gist below, I was wondering if someone could shed some light on why this error is occurring?

https://gist.github.com/matt-major/32f53036643e3fc7c65e

Comment: This seems a bit needlessly complicated https://gist.github.com/matt-major/32f53036643e3fc7c65e#file-app-ts-L17-L18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have the module as a class

```
export class app {

    private angularModule: ng.IModule;

    /**
     * The Class Constructor
     */
    constructor() {

      swordfish.helpers.registerDependencies(['ngRoute']);
      this.angularModule = angular.module('swordfish', swordfish.helpers.registeredDependencies);
      this.moduleRegister('swordfish.controllers', swordfish.controllers);
```

What I don't see is someone *calling* it. You would need to get the line `angular.module('swordfish', swordfish.helpers.registeredDependencies);` executed for `angular` to detect this module.

Comment: Thanks, I added `swordfish.app = new swordfish.app();` to the bottom of `app.ts` & it worked. I had to change a few other bits around the controller registration but it's now working correctly. Appreciate the help.